# Input Parameter for callback function Web3

Tags: web3js, javascript

I want to send the parameter to the function in smart contract i tried different ways but it keeps giving me error.

My solidity file is

```
 pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

 import "./ConvertLib.sol";

 contract Check {
 function multiply(uint a) public pure returns(uint){
    return a*a;
 }
}
```

I connected to Web3 sucessfully and created the instance of contract as inst. When i try to execute the function

```
 console.log(inst.multiply.call()(function(err,result){console.log("r-->"+result);}));
```

it gives me error

```
Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function
```

and if i add argument like this

```
console.log(inst.multiply(2).call()(function(err,result){console.log("r-->"+result);}));
```

or like this

```
console.log(inst.multiply.call(2)(function(err,result){console.log("r-->"+result);}));
```

it gives me this error

```
Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_call without a callback parameter.
```

I am using Web3 version 0.20.3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the web3 [docs](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call):

> myContract.methods.myMethod([param1[, param2[, ...]]]).call(options[,
>   callback])

#### Truffle and Ganache

```
inst.methods.multiply(2).call()
    .then(function(result) {
        console.log("r-->"+result);
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.log("err-->"+err);
    }
);
```

Or, simpler:

```
inst.methods.multiply(2).call().then(console.log).catch(console.log);
```

#### Metamask

```
inst.multiply(2, function(err, result) {
    console.log("r-->"+result);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, yes thats make me confuse . But still same error on both solution. Error: The MetaMask Web3 object does not support synchronous methods like eth_call without a callback parameter.

Comment: I see, there are different instructions for interacting with MetaMask. You can check out my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, after that i got new error Metamask: invalid json rpc response 32603 and i overcome that by using testrpc and then it works:)

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
inst.multiply(2,function(err,res){console.log(res)})
```

Hope this helps